# Cosmos DB - How to remove a unique index

Tags: indexing, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure Cosmos DB (MongoDB) and I want to remove a unique index from a collection's field.

We removed the unwanted index from the system.indexes collection but nothing happened.

On the documentation, we can see these two options to update the Indexing Policy:

1- Submenu "Settings" under the "Collections" section (it shoulb be next to "Browse" and "Scale").

2- By going to a "Data Explorer", select a collection, "Scale and Settings"

But we don't have access to those buttons/sections.

Is there a way to remove a unique index without creating a new db and migrate all the data? This would be bad as we would need to change the db name, the db name on the code, etc

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do using [dropIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/), however, in CosmosDB that only works if the [collection is empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing#migrating-collections-with-indexes). You will need to move the documents out of the collection, remove the index, and then move the documents back.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like changing unique keys in Azure CosmosDB is not allowed after the container is created.

> You can't update an existing container to use a different unique key. In other words, after a container is created with a unique key policy, the policy can't be changed.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys#define-a-unique-key